# How does Central City PD jail metahumans?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

Part of *The Flash* is that they tend to <strike>kidnap and deny constitutional rights to</strike> capture evil Metahumans and keep them in the particle accelerator. That works because of some pseudo science about how the particle accelerator works.

In Season 2, it turns out that Iron Heights, the prison in/near Central City, can now safely harbor metahumans (within the confines of the criminal justice system). How exactly did they do that? Did Star Labs share the exact specs for the particle accelerator? Did they construct the same type of cells?

What is the (in-universe) science behind it?

Answer (score 6):

Per the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Heights_Penitentiary#Television) regarding the prison, specifically the Arrow-verse version:

> Iron Heights was initially incapable of housing metahumans, as
>   described by S.T.A.R. Labs founder Dr. Harrison Wells, and the **remnant
>   of the Labs' particle accelerator served as a makeshift prison for
>   metahuman criminals** while S.T.A.R. Labs work on reversing their
>   mutations.

And, later in the entry:

> By Season Two, the public 'acceptance' of metahumans has **resulted in a
>   new wing being established for metahuman prisoners**...

So it would seem Iron Heights has been retrofit with cells that are capable of holding metahuman prisoners, either using the same remnants of S.T.A.R. Labs, or constructing new ones.

Comment: Wasn't there something special about the Accelerator that stopped the powers?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'd have to re-watch the episode where they decide to use it. Can likely do that at some point tonight.

Answer (score -4):

They created bracelets to stop powers. Killer flash wanted to use them in season 2 episode 6.

Comment: Did bracelets appeared before? Not noticed it in the previous seasons